# Storage Manager in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, database-backups

I am trying to backup one of my databases in PostgreSQL pgAdmin tool. I used this tutorial:
[backup database with pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/backup_dialog.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20backup%20a%20single,in%20the%20dialog%20title%20bar.)

After finishing that I want to have the file. In that tutorial it says that we can use the **Storage Manager** to download the backup file on the client machine. After that from [this link](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/storage_manager.html) I wanted to access the **Storage Manager**. It says that "You can access Storage Manager from the Tools Menu", but from my system there is not any option with that name:

[image: tools menu of pgAdmin]

What is the problem and how could I obtain the backup database file?

Comment: Are you using pgadmin4 *in server mode*?

Comment: @jjanes, I am using pgAdmin4 but I am not sure it is in the server mode or not. how could I find and use it?

Comment: If you didn't go out of your way to put it in server mode, then it isn't.  If you are running locally, the exported data is already stored locally, so there is no point in downloading it as it is already there.

Comment: @jjanes, I run it in my local computer. could you please tell me which folder it stores usually by default?  is it the directory that I installed "postgresql" and if it is there, in which folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not running pgAdmin4 in server mode, then there is no storage manager.  The storage manager is only relevant when the computer from which you run the pgAdmin4 GUI is different from the computer where the pgAdmin4 app-server is running.

When you took the backup, you told it where to save the file although not in a very user-friendly way.  It asks for a filename, and there are three dots you can click to browse for a directory into which to put the file.  But if you don't avail yourself of the three dots, then you don't know where it is going to put the file, it just uses an apparently OS-dependent default and doesn't tell you what it is.  I usually find in my "Documents" folder. (Well, I usually don't use pgAdmin4 in the first place as it makes everything harder than just using the command line is, but when I do use it...)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I found the file in the "Documents" folder. but when open it, it has wrong encoding. I set encoding to "UTF8". is it wrong? how could I find the right encoding?